# Update post meta dynamically

Tags: post-meta

I am trying to insert/update post meta when the user registers. Before writing that action, I am testing this code on the page so whenever the page refresh it will insert/update the post meta.

> **Question:** However, the below code is not inserting/updating anything in post
>   meta. Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code or how to fix it?

```
$groupItem = get_post(123);

if ($groupItem && $groupItem->post_type == 'cpt_group') {

    $meta     = 'group_users';
    $user_ids = get_post_meta($groupItem->ID, $meta, TRUE);

    if ( ! $user_ids) {
        $user_ids = [];
        add_post_meta($groupItem->ID, $meta, array_push($user_ids, 26));
    } else {
        update_post_meta($groupItem->ID, $meta, array_push($user_ids, 26), $user_ids);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you're not properly using `array_push()`.

[`array_push()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) modifies the original/input array which is [passed by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) to the function and it returns the new number of elements in the array.

So with `add_post_meta( $groupItem->ID, $meta, array_push( $user_ids, 26 ) )`, you're actually setting the meta value to the number of items in `$user_ids` and not the items in the array — so for example, `add_post_meta()` would get a `1` instead of a `[26]`.

So if you want to use `array_push()`, you could do it like so:

```php
if ( ! $user_ids ) {
    $user_ids = [];
    array_push( $user_ids, 26 );
    add_post_meta( $groupItem->ID, $meta, $user_ids );
} else {
    $prev_user_ids = $user_ids; // backup old values
    array_push( $user_ids, 26 );
    update_post_meta( $groupItem->ID, $meta, $user_ids, $prev_user_ids );
}
```

Or simply use `$user_ids[] = 26;` ..

Comment: Perfect. Solved the issue. But stuck with another related issue. The code works fine if I run directly on the page load but if I run using `user_register` action hook. Nothing is happening. I don't know why. I will post a new question for it. Thanks again.

Comment: In case if you can help me on that https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/360325/update-post-meta-using-user-register-hook-not-working