# update post meta using user_register hook not working

Tags: hooks, user-registration

I want to update post meta when the user registers based on the Ultimate Member plugin field in the register form. Here is the code which is working fine if I run directly on the template (loading page) but not working with the hook.

> **Note**: As I mention the code is working as expected if I run on template file (refreshing page) but not with the hook.

```
function gs_add_user_to_group($user_id)
{
    // get the user group by profile
    $groupItem = get_post(um_user('team'));

    // check if post is exists and is a group post type
    if ($groupItem && $groupItem->post_type == Group_Shop_Admin::get_cpt_group()) {

        // get group post meta
        $meta         = gs_get_group_meta_key('users');
        $old_user_ids = get_post_meta($groupItem->ID, $meta, TRUE);

        // check if empty
        if ( ! $old_user_ids) {
            $user_ids = [];
        } else {
            $user_ids = $old_user_ids;
        }

        // push newly register user id
        array_push($user_ids, $user_id);

        if ( ! $old_user_ids) {
            // add new record if not exits
            add_post_meta($groupItem->ID, $meta, $user_ids);
        } else {
            // update and add newly register user id to record
            update_post_meta($groupItem->ID, $meta, $user_ids, $old_user_ids);
        }
    }
}

add_action('user_register', 'gs_add_user_to_group', 10, 1);
/* End of  gs_add_user_to_group hook */
```

Comment: Usermeta doesn't exist in the database yet when `user_register` runs. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155566/get-first-name-and-last-name-on-user-register-hook

Comment: @WebElaine that is what I thought. So is there any alternatives?

Comment: By "run directly", did you mean you manually called `gs_add_user_to_group()` in your template? And how did you (or what steps you took which let you) know it doesn't work with the hook - and by that, you mean your function isn't getting called or that the *post* meta is not being added or updated? And I actually tried `wp_insert_user()` and your code worked fine.

Comment: I have directly checked into the database. So when running on template it is updating the record but through the action hook.

Comment: I see it now. `um_user()` retrieves a user meta/data. So perhaps the answer can help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part that does not work in your code is not adding or updating the post meta, but *getting the user meta named `team` which you're retrieving via [`um_user()`](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/158-umuser)*.

And that's because as [@WebElaine](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/102815/webelaine) pointed, by the time the `user_register` hook is fired, the custom field `team` has *not* yet added to the database (neither by WordPress nor UM), hence `um_user( 'team' )` returns nothing/`false`.

But if you want to use the `user_register` hook to add/update the post meta, you can use the `$_POST['team']` value submitted via the form. So replace this:

```php
$groupItem = get_post(um_user('team'));
```

with this:

```php
if ( $post_id = um_user( 'team' ) ) {
    $groupItem = get_post( $post_id );
// I'm just doing a basic validation, but you should try to make it better!
} elseif ( ! empty( $_POST['team'] ) ) {
    $groupItem = get_post( absint( $_POST['team'] ) );
}
```

Or since you're relying upon the `team` meta which came from user input submitted via the UM's registration form, then it might better to use [`um_registration_complete` hook](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1234-umregistrationcomplete) to add/update the post meta:

1. First, call `um_fetch_user()` before you call `um_user()`:

   ```php
   um_fetch_user( $user_id ); // set the user
   $groupItem = get_post( um_user( 'team' ) );
   ```

   Alternatively, you can use `get_user_meta()`:

   ```php
   $post_id = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'team', true );
   $groupItem = get_post( $post_id );
   ```
2. And replace the `add_action('user_register', 'gs_add_user_to_group', 10, 1);` with this:

   ```php
   add_action( 'um_registration_complete', 'gs_add_user_to_group', 10, 2 );
   ```

***Tried & tested working on WordPress 5.3.2 with UM 2.1.4.***

Comment: Amazing help. Thanks a lot. That's the hook I was looking some hours ago and going to give it a try. Before that, I read your answer and found even if I tried, I would miss `um_fetch_user( $user_id );` :) thanks once again. (y)

Comment: You're welcome, and I also actually almost missed that `um_fetch_user()` thing. :) Also, you don't need to use the `10, 2` in the `add_action()` call.. I use the `2` when checking the `$args` passed via that [hook](https://docs.ultimatemember.com/article/1234-umregistrationcomplete). :)

Comment: Cool, thanks to a lot. That will help too.